# Slackware init rd_local problem

Tags: linux, slackware, init

I have made an error in the rd_local file which, Linux is having problem starting up because of this. Is there any way I can edit this file without starting up or am I screwed?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean rc.local file?

Anyway, if you want to edit files but do not want (or can't) boot from hard disc, do this:

1) Boot your system with the Slackware install DVD or first CD using whatever kernel options you need to see your hard disk. Once logged in and presented with the console, mount your root partition to /mnt with the following command (assuming your root partition is /dev/hda3)

```
mount /dev/hda3 /mnt
```

2) chroot into the system with this command

```
chroot /mnt
```

3) Once chrooted, you may edit configuration files